# Why do we use the context API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I had this thought occur to me today. I've been learning React for a bit, and I often hear the Context API as a shared data source for nested components. You instantiate a context, wrap all the components you want to have access to in that context's provider, and do what you need to with that data inside each component.

My question then is essentially, why do we use the Context API instead of just using a shared reference to a value inside a module? At the end of the day the `useContext` hook and `Context.Consumer` require an amount of code roughly equivalent to simply importing a module across all the components that need access to its data.

I'm struggling to understand how using the Context API actually solves any problems that couldn't just as easily be solved with what the browser already provides us, so what am I missing here?

Comment: You can find out what it does from here [Context - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Changing things in contexts make React to re-render upon changes while in regular modules it doesn't.

Comment: You don't have to use Context it's just a built in way to both share state and re-render components (in some cases unnecessarily due to it's shortcomings). You could have a module which either provides a Higher Order Component that re-renders the React tree under it, or a React Hook which does - this is what most global state libs do (which is pretty trivial to implement yourself)

Comment: At its most basic level it solves the issue of prop drilling when you have lifted enough state to a high enough common ancestor. You won't need to pass through (the drilling) a bunch of props to descendent components that intermediate components don't care or need to even know about. It's like a "pipe" to pass props on to grand-children and great-grand-children. Other than this, the [official Context docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) explain the purpose pretty well.

Comment: you can also have multiple providers of the same context in the component tree. That's a benefit of contexts over "shared state" other frameworks use.

Comment: It isn't about sharing components, it's about sharing state. React uses one-way data flow, that is, you can only share state from parent to child(as props). You cant share state between two components in the same level without moving the state one level up. Context API solved this issue.